# Best practice to share projects across different solutions using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have 2 Solution, call them solution A & B.
Each solution have 2 projects:

- Solution A: ProjectX which also reference project Common
- Solution B: ProjectY which also reference project Common

Common is a project which contains some of the independent similar classes.

Each of the projectsX/Y have is using it's own global variable when running.
For both X/Y I have:

```
public class Globals
{
    public static dynamic vaProxy;
    ...
}
```

When each solution A/B is running is first creates this **Globals.vaProxy** which is used across many classes as well as sets numerous other global variables,

E.g. I may call:

```
Globals.vaProxy.WriteToLog("somthing...")
```

Or I may access:

```
Globals.someVAriableName
```

What I am trying to do is to move similar classes to the Common project so that I will not have to write them twice.

Currently the Common project has only classes which do not require the use of Globals.vaProxy or Globals.someVar.

Is there a way I can move a class which requires a global variable to the Common project even though it has no Global definition?

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection

Comment: yes and maybe (for the OP) first https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you look at/think about/research:

- IOC (inversion of control)
- DI (dependency injection)
- coding to a contract (use of Interfaces)

But in essence it sounds like you really just want to:

- have some **common code in one project**
- have that **common project consumed by various different projects/slns**
- have different consumers (of the common code) give their **own (different) instances of Globals** / Globals.vaProxy to the common code (so it can work with their data in a generic way)

If that is a decent description(?) then the **essential answer is that you should change the classes** (which you can't currently "get into" Common.csproj as they reference Globals and/or Globals.vaProxy) **so they don't work with a concrete type, but instead use an interface**.

e.g.

change relevant method signatures (for code you want to move to Common.csproj) from **using specific classes** e.g.

```
public void DoSomethingCommon(Globals globalInstance)
```

To use **interfaces instead**:

```
public void DoSomethingCommon(IGlobals globalInstance)
```

Then expose IGlobals from the common project to it's consumers.

```
public interface IGlobals {
   //whatever members are required in Common, maybe... 
   dynamic vaProxy {get; set;}
}
```

Then you can **implement that IGlobals interface** in the different concrete classes in the consuming projects/slns.

e.g.

```
namespace SpecificConsumer 
{
    public class Globals : Common.IGlobals 
    {
    //Whatever
    }
}
```

That way the **common code works with what it needs** to be true of each different Globals implementation, and `each consumer of Common can implement as it needs`.

**Note** that you don't need to actually define anything in that interface... it can simply be a **marker interface** which just "labels" some concrete class as "acceptable". This might seem odd, but is actually quite standard.

**How about:**

```
namespace Common
{
    public interface IVaProxy { }

    public class SomeCommonFunctionality
    {
        public static bool DoWork(IVaProxy specificInstanceOfVaProxy)
        {
            dynamic instanceAsDyn = (dynamic)specificInstanceOfVaProxy;
            if (instanceAsDyn.SomeThingIsTrue)
                return ((dynamic)specificInstanceOfVaProxy).SomeMemberReturningBool();
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**And in Proj/sln A:**

```
using Common;

namespace ConsumerA
{
    public class Globals
    {
        public static Common.IVaProxy vaProxy { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConsumerOfCommonInA
    {
        public static void Test()
        {
            Common.SomeCommonFunctionality.DoWork(Globals.vaProxy);
        }
    }
}
```

**In Proj/sln B:**

```
using Common;

namespace ConsumerB
{
    public class Globals
    {
        public static Common.IVaProxy vaProxy { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeClassInB
    {
        public static void DiffferentWork()
        {
            Common.SomeCommonFunctionality.DoWork(Globals.vaProxy);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If common needs to work with something, make an interface that describes that need. Mark classes in the consumers with that interface. Reference Common project from different consumers. Consumers then use the common code by passing their types to the relevant members (this works as their types implement the common interface(s)).

Comment: Please add more info if this doesn't help you.

Comment: Note - be careful using dynamic like you are. Certainly in the Common project you should work out what the common code needs to work with, make an interface for that, and implement that interface (the commonality) in the consuming projects (A/B/X). Dynamic is awesome and powerful - but do you REALLY want/need it here? If you do specific things with specific data - then work out what those specifics actually are and record that as an interface.

Comment: For a "proper" approach consider something like this https://github.com/shaynevanasperen/Code

Comment: Thank you.  I could use interfaces but what wanted to refrain from is from passing, in this case vaproxy every time i access a method/class which requires it.
E.g. here: Common.SomeCommonFunctionality.DoWork(Globals.vaProxy);
I am passing the global var to the methos/class. Since I am constantly using it, it means passing it all the time

Comment: The issue is not only with a single global variable. there are numerous global variable I am currently not passing to the common methods (common yet duplicated)

Comment: To avoid needing to constantly pass instances from the consumers to the common code, you could pass a single object with properties for everything you need at a suitable time (e.g. app startup). You could have a Global class in common, and do e.g. Common.Globals.Set(projectXInstance); Then Common.Globals can expose that whole object from a static property. Then you only pass one object one time, and all the common code can do it's work easily. This is crude but easy to do and easy to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see many alternatives:

1. create a nuget package ("Common", or something better named) if you can share publicly this is good when you do not need to recompile Common often.
2. put Common project into Solution A (as subdirectory) and reference it as existing project from solution B.

> Is there a way I can move a class which requires a global variable to
> the Common project even though it has no Global definition?

Yes, that is:

1. an interface exposing your variable, and the implementation (ie., the concrete class, with definitions) is injected through the constructor:

```
public interface IGlobalVariables
{
    public string Value { get; }
    public string GetValue();
}

public class Globals: IGlobalVariables
{
    public string Value => "an example";
    public string GetValue() => "an example";
}

public class ProjectClass
{
    public IGlobalVariables GlobalVariables { get; } // no definition
    
    public ProjectClass(IGlobalVariables globalVariables)
    {
        GlobalVariables = globalVariables;
    }
}
```

2. Very close but with less flexibility (you can't cumulate interfaces, but you can share one implementation to all subclasses), an abstract function (it has no definition) that must be overriden in a subclass:

```
public abstract class Globals
{
    public abstract string Value { get; }
    public abstract string GetValue();
}

public class SpecialGlobal: Globals
{
    public override string Value => "some content";
    public override string GetValue() => "some content";
}
```

Comment: Nuget is a good suggestion, but perhaps for the OP a bit OTT. If this is a good path for the OP - I highly recommend source-only nugets. Not usual but a good example is https://github.com/shaynevanasperen/Quarks